# Two physics bodies go over each other in sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Swift
SpriteKit
I'm having an issue where i have 2 nodes (a player & a block) usually avoiding each other. I'm using touch to move the player as the code shows.
Usually when I'm moving the player it successfully hits the block. But when i move my finger in a fast way, the player can go over the block and stay on it. I need to prevent the player from ever getting over the block.

I'm new to this so please all details will help.

In the sks scene I defined the following under the attributes inspector of the block:
Bounding rectangle,
Dynamic,
Pinned,
does not allow rotation,
Not affected by gravity

The player:
Bounding rectangle,
Dynamic,
Not Pinned,
does not allow rotation,
Not affected by gravity

Under touchesMoved func:

```
        let Touch : UITouch! = touches.first
        let TouchLocation = Touch.locationInNode(self)
        let PreviousTouchLocation = Touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

        let Player = childNodeWithName("Player") as! SKSpriteNode

        let xPos = Player.position.x + (TouchLocation.x - PreviousTouchLocation.x)
        let yPos = Player.position.y + (TouchLocation.y - PreviousTouchLocation.y)

        Player.position = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos)
```

Also, how can I apply an alpha mask using code.

Comment: Try adding a SKAction to move the player. At the moment your player position is just jumping to the next position and it is not registering everything in between. Instead of player.position = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos), try using player.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(xPos, yPos), duration: 0.1)). Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: He moved too slowly so I made the duration 0.01. He now moves at a good rate but the problem persists. He still "jumps" over blocks & even stay at them. Moreover, this new way of moving him introduced a new problem. The player is now "vibrating" as he moves.